# Tree with exfoliating bark and ovate leaves

Tags: identification, trees

I'd like to identify this tree, growing on the margin of a drainage ditch next to a fairly dry gravel parking lot in coastal Maine, USA (hardiness zone 5b). It's currently about 8' tall, with opposite branching; exfoliating bark; 6" ovate leaves with fine-toothed serrated margins that occur in clusters. It is currently (August) flowering, with multiple small white buds along a 10" central stems emerging from the centers of most leaf clusters. Sniffing the (perhaps mostly gone by) flowers over a couple of days indicated no odor.

Some pictures. First, the whole tree:

[image: Whole tree]

Second, a leaf cluster viewed from the top and the side:

[image: Leaf cluster, top]

[image: Leaf cluster, side]

The flowers:

[image: Flowers]

... one flower in closeup:
[image: Flower close-up]

And the trunk:

[image: Trunk]

and a closeup of the bark (with newspaper to persuade my cell camera to focus):
[image: Bark]

(Feel free to correct my terminology, and thanks.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its Clethra, and as it's in flower now, Clethra alnifolia, although you haven't mentioned fragrance in regard to the flowers, and they are fragrant. Common name sweet pepperbush or summersweet, it's a deciduous shrub hardy down to USDA zone 3. It likes moist soil, which explains why it's chosen to grow on the edge of the drainage ditch, and is native to your area. More info https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/all/clethra-alnifolia/

Comment: Interesting, and close, but I don't think it's a match. I sniffed the (albeit mostly closed) flowers, and there's no scent. Plus, the organization seems wrong; the plant I'm describing clearly has a single central bole, but Clethra seems to be a bush, with [lots of stems](https://www.google.com/search?q=Clethra+alnifolia&tbm=isch). Is there more info I can collect that would confirm/refute your suggestion?

Comment: Wait till the flowers open, try to smell them when the sun is on them...but I sort of agree about its growth habit, this one looks more like a tree...

Comment: Bamboo I think your ID is correct.  This is usually a shrub a medium to large which can as you know be a small tree. Easy to prune it into a small tree but if this is the case, someone has been working on this guy from the beginning.

Comment: @stormy Or its grown without any interference - it is an upright grower, and often, professional growers prune back as a plant grows to make it bushy... Scent of flowers and seedpods later will confirm or deny

Comment: It looks to be growing amongst trees, so quite shady, which would encourage more upright growth. Scent as an ident won't work for everyone - I love the smell of Platanus leaves which I find quite strong and point it out to people in my garden and a quite a few have unable to smell anything.

Comment: @Georgeofalltrades Its absolutely true what you say about sense of smell, but the scent for this is described as 'sickly sweet', I imagine something like Lilium regale (I never cut those for indoors, they end up going back outside if I do, too sickly sweet and strong) but never having smelt Clethra flowers, I don't know how strong the scent is, but it sounds like it should be detectable. I  know people who love the smell of cut Choisya; I find it literally revolting, so yea, sense of smell varies enormously

Comment: I tried sniffing the flowers again today, and there is almost no odor from them. Again, though, the flowers seem mostly past their prime.